# Is vanishing KL a problem in vision based VAEs as well?

Tags: vae

I came across some work on the problem of a vanishing KL contrbution in Variational Auto Encoders [Cyclical Annealing Schedule: A Simple Approach to Mitigating KL Vanishing](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.10145). This work particularly is in the NLP space where they use recurrent neural networks to model sentences which yields to the vanishing KL term problem.

I wonder if there is a similar issue when working with convolutional networks and images.

Cheers